# Light mode flickers for a second when reloading page in dark mode

Tags: javascript, dom-events, darkmode

I'm working on a JavaScript code snippet that implements a dark/light mode toggle feature on a web page using cookie to store user preference. However, I'm experiencing a flickering issue when I reload the page in dark mode. So when I reload the page in dark mode light mode in appearing for a second and then switch it back to dark mode when page fully loads.

I've tried local storage by setting darkmode = true when user is in dark mode , but still facing light mode flicker for a second when I reload the page in dark mode.

I am putting the JS code in  tag above all links and style tags.

Here is the JS code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    const darkModeToggle = document.getElementById('dark-light');
    const darkModeElement = document.querySelector('.dark-mode');
    const lightModeElement = document.querySelector('.light-mode');
    const bodyElement = document.body;

    // Check if dark mode preference exists in the cookie
    const isDarkMode = getCookie('darkMode');

    // Set dark mode based on the preference
    if (isDarkMode === 'true') {
        bodyElement.classList.add('dark-theme');
        darkModeElement.style.display = 'block';
        lightModeElement.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        bodyElement.classList.remove('dark-theme');
        darkModeElement.style.display = 'none';
        lightModeElement.style.display = 'block';
    }

    darkModeToggle.addEventListener('click', () => {
        // Toggle dark mode class and save preference in the cookie
        bodyElement.classList.toggle('dark-theme');
        darkModeElement.style.display = darkModeElement.style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
        lightModeElement.style.display = lightModeElement.style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
        const isDarkMode = bodyElement.classList.contains('dark-theme');
        setCookie('darkMode', isDarkMode, 365);
    });

    // Function to set a cookie
    function setCookie(name, value, days) {
        const expires = new Date();
        expires.setTime(expires.getTime() + days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        document.cookie = name + '=' + value + ';expires=' + expires.toUTCString() + ';path=/';
    }

    // Function to get a cookie value
    function getCookie(name) {
        const cookieArr = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (let i = 0; i < cookieArr.length; i++) {
            const cookiePair = cookieArr[i].split('=');
            if (cookiePair[0].trim() === name) {
                return cookiePair[1];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
});
```

Here is html:

```
<div id='dark-light'>
        <div class="dark-mode">
            <img src="./sun.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="light-mode hidden">
            <img src="./moon.png" alt="moon-image">
        </div>
</div>
```